# Update ideavim: remap <ctrl+j> for <b> and <ctrl+l> for <w> not working

Tags: android-studio, ideavim

New update of plugin ideavim make my remap not working, how can I resolve it ?

He now make some tab indentation, I don't realy understand what is going on.
I just want to move on previous word typing `<C-h>` & `<C-l>` to move on next one.

Here is my `.ideavimrc` file:

```
" -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
" Navigation
" -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

" Go to next/previous word
nnoremap <C-h> <b>
nnoremap <C-l> <w>
vnoremap <C-h> <b>
vnoremap <C-l> <w>
nnoremap <C-S-h> <B>
nnoremap <C-S-l> <W>
vnoremap <C-S-h> <B>
vnoremap <C-S-l> <W>


" Insert Mode
inoremap <C-h> <Left>
inoremap <C-j> <Down>
inoremap <C-k> <Up>
inoremap <C-l> <Right>
cnoremap <C-h> <Left>
cnoremap <C-j> <Down>
cnoremap <C-k> <Up>
cnoremap <C-l> <Right>
```

Comment: Use the plugin's own [support channel](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim/discussions).

Answer (score 0):

Someone find the solution here:
[Github forum](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim/discussions/423#discussioncomment-1794472)